# How should I call input fields in post request

Tags: c#, post, model-view-controller

How should I call input fields that they will be correct maping in post request?

```
public class ViolationTypes
{
         public int ViolationTypeId {get; set; }
         public string ViolationDate {get; set; }
}


public List <ViolationTypes> ViolationTypeIds {get; set; }
```

I named it so but does not work

```
var name1 = String.Format ("{0} .ViolationTypeIds [{1}]. ViolationTypeId", prefix, item.Value);
var name2 = String.Format ("{0} .ViolationTypeIds [{1}]. ViolationDate", prefix, item.Value);
```

prefix - this is the current Tab

View:

```
foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var name1 = String.Format("{0}.ViolationTypeIds.ViolationTypeId", prefix, item.Value);
            var name2 = String.Format("{0}.ViolationTypeIds.ViolationDate", prefix, item.Value);
            var id1 = fieldName + "_" + item.Value;
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20px">
                    @if (isDisabled)
                    {
                        <input disabled="disabled" name="@name1" value="@item.Value" id="@id1" @(item.Selected ? "checked=\" checked\"" : string.Empty) />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <input type="checkbox" name="@name1" value="@item.Value" id="@id1" @(item.Selected ? "checked=\" checked\"" : string.Empty) />
                    }
                </th>
                <td>
                    <label for="@id1">@item.Text</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="@name2"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Update([Bind(Exclude = "CurrentTab")] 
            TabViewModel currentTab, FormAction action){}
```

Comment: can you show, please, your view and action code?

Comment: I edited my post and wrote View markup and Controller head

Answer (score 0):

try to use this construct to render your model. tags omited for brevity, you can add them yourself.

```
    @for (var index = 0; index < Model.ViolationTypes.Length; index++)
    {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ViolationTypes[index].ViolationTypeId)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.ViolationTypes[index].Value)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ViolationTypes[index].ViolationDate)
    }
```

Comment: I can't do this because it helper:                                                      @helper CheckBoxDateListHtml(IEnumerable<Rgi.Esugi.Web.Register.Html.SelectListWithDateItem> items, string fieldName, HtmlHelper html)
{

Comment: @Blackraven - What does that mean?